# Simple multi-domain email management under linux

Tags: linux, email, postfix, provider

I was looking to a way to deploy a simple email ecosystem, with postfix, dovecot and antispam/antivirus milters in a fast and easy way, without configuring them one by one manually.

I saw iRedMail, and it's good (not so much for amavis, but I can deal with it) because is a simple and fast deploy, with everything you need to start.

Are there any (free, if possibile) alternatives? Maybe a full distro dedicated for this or a panel to manage easily everything.

Thank you

Comment: May be the better way is to contract someone to launch service? Opensource toolset that resemble most iRedMail functionality can be installed and configured in a less than a day.

Comment: I know how to do it, but I'm just tired to spend time configuring it... iRedMail get things easy, but the control panel it's not free and is also using postqueue methods to scan emails. Obviusly I can uninstall amavis and install a milter, but it takes time and effort. I was just looking for a way to get things clear without pain.